# Is DAO microservice good approach in microservices architecture?

Tags: web-services, rest, database-design, architecture, microservices

I'm creating a web-application and decided to use micro-services approach. Would you please tell me what is the best approach or at least common to organize access to the database from all web-services (login, comments and etc. web-services). Is it well to create DAO web-service and use only it to to read/write values in the database of the application. Or each web-service should have its own dao layer.

Answer (score 3):

Each microservice should be a full-fledged application with all necessary layers (which doesn't mean there cannot be shared *code* between microservices, but they have to run in separate processes).

Besides, it is often recommended that each microservice have its own database. See http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-at-netflix-architectural-best-practices/ Therefore, I don't really see the point of a web service that would only act as a data access facade.

Answer (score 3):

Microservices are great, but it is not good to start with too many microservices right away. If you have doubt about how to define the boundaries between microservices in your application, start by a monolith (all the time keeping the code clean and a good object-oriented with well designed layers and interfaces). When you get to a more mature state of the application, you will more easily see the right places to split to independently deployable services.

The key is to keep together things that should really be coupled. When we try to decouple everything from everything, we end up creating too many layers of interfaces, and this slows us down.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good approach.
DB operation is critical in any process, so it must be in the DAO layer inside de microservice. Why you don't what to implement inside.
Using a service, you loose control, and if you have to change the process logic you have to change DAO service (Affecting to all the services).
In my opinion it is not good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using Services to expose data from a database is ideal due to the flexibility it provides. Development of a REST service to expose some or all of your data as a service provides flexibility to consume the data directly to the UI via AJAX or by other services which can process the data and generate new information. These consumers do not need to implement a DAO and can be in any language. While a REST Service of your entire database is probably not a Micro-Service, a case could be made for breaking this down as Read only for Students, Professors and Classes for exposing on the School Web site(s), with different services for Create, Update and Delete (CUD) available only to the Registrars office desktop applications.

For example building a Service to exposes a statistical value on data will protect the data from examination by a user/program who only needs a statistical value without the requirement of having the service implement an entire DAO for the components of that statistic. Full function databases like SQL Server or Oracle provide a lot of functionality that application developers can use, including complex queries(using indexes), statistics the application of set operations on data.

Answer (score -1):

Having a database service is a completely valid pattern. In fact, this is one of the key examples of where to start to export aspects of a monolith to a micro service in the [Building Microservices book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033158.do).

How to organize your code around such idea is a different issue. Yes, from the db client programmer's stand point, having the same DAO layer on each DB client makes a lot of sense.

The DAO pattern may be suitable to bind your DB to one programming language that you use. But then you need to ask yourself why you are exposing your database as a web service if all access to it will be mediated by the same DAO infrastructure. Or are you going to create one DAO pattern for each client programming language binding?

If all database clients are going to be written on the same programming language, then are you sure you really need to wrap your DB as a microservice? After all, the DB is usually already a remote service with a well-defined network protocol optimized to transfer data fast and reliably. Why adding HTTP on top of it? What are you expecting to gain from adding such complexity?

Another problem with using the DAO pattern is that the DAO structure does not necessarily follow the evolution of the web service. The web service may evolve in a way that does not make old clients incompatible. You may have different clients using different features of the micro service. In this case you are not sharing the same DAO layer structure on each client.

Make sure you are not using RPC-style programming over web services, which does not make much sense. You will be basically throwing away one of the key advantages of micro services, which is the decoupling between service and client.

Comment: Can you quote the Building Microservices book where it says that a *database service is a completely valid pattern*?

Comment: You have confused RPC technologies (Java RMI, CORBA) which indeed introduce a coupling between the server and the client and RPC-style programming, which related to the way you design your API. You can have a REST web service using open protocols (HTTP) not enforcing any coupling on the clients but designed so that it enforces RPC-style programming (Level 0 in Richardson Maturity Model).